# Create a solution and run it for an ASP.net website that has code only in folders

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, solution

I have a website that is currently running on IIS for an internal website for a company.
I didn't receive a solution to open in Visual Studio, I only have a folder with the files that are deployed in the production server on an "asp_applications" folder. 
Inside of it there is one folder for each website's code, so far I've been modifying the aspx.inc and aspx files in a notepad++ in order to do some bug fixing, and tweaking of functionalities, but not having a proper setup in Visual Studio is limiting my ability to work.

I tried creating a solution in Visual Studio and adding the folder with the code:

[image]

the website in production opens to **http://XXXX.YYYY.com/index.aspx?fuseaction=home.approvepos** so I went to my new solution and opened the index.asp file. which has the following:

[image]

here I tried to run and get an error
[image]

after clicking yes I get the following error

[image]

and following this instruction I added the required piece to the web.config

```
    <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="false" />
    </appSettings>
```

[image]

however I'm still not able to run in local this page. can you help me understand what am I doing wrong? I would like this so I can debug my website and have some intellisense and normal stuff from the IDE to be able to develop a little easier.

please let me know if there is more information I could provide.

Thank you and have a great day :)

P.S. this is a small list of the type of files that there is
[image]

Comment: Why did you tag this as ASP Classic and mention it in your title? I see no evidence that ASP Classic is in use here - just ASP.NET Web Forms.

Comment: You really need the original source code and project. With asp.net what is deployed is not really designed for editing in place. `.cs` files are more often than not compiled into a binary. Furthermore `UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext` was introduced in asp.net 4.5 , if the original project predates that you will have issues if you've set up your project as asp.net 4.5 or greater. Why don't you have the original source? Is it lost or are there policies in place that don't allow you access to it?

Comment: My comment above then raises the question, how are you source/versioning controlling the code base? In *any* kind of coding environment for commercial use there **needs** to be some kind of versioning control for the code base.

Comment: Hello Jon, thank you for taking the time: 
there is no versioning in place,  I have started using GIT to do it but there wasn't anything in place, at all!. I know, it's awful practice. and on regards of code, everything I have is those .aspx.inc files (I think this is the deployed code, not the proper source code). would a list of all the files I have help? I'll compile one and attach it to the question. thank you for taking the time to try to help me

Comment: A list won't really help. You can't reliably take deployed files and recreate the original project. ASP.net just doesn't work like that. You *may* be able to get something cobbled together with what you have. For a start you'll probably need to create a new project but see if you can work out what version from the original deployed `web.config` file. Though the the best source for that would normally be the original `.proj` file.

Comment: there is no original web.config and no .proj file. what does this means? that the person that coded originally didn't left the source code? I'm just out of luck here?

Comment: My previous comment got deleted (possibly flagged as rude due to a colourful description) so I'll repeat it, but a little more professionally. Yes you are more than likely out of luck. There are hints in the code (`Server.execute`, lots of includes, no `web.config`) that his is mash up between classic asp (possibly PHP) and asp.net webforms, where the previous developer has almost done a line by line port of the original site, ignoring the methodologies and best practices of asp.net of the time.

Comment: I understand. ok, so it's kinda what I was thinking, anyways, thank you very much for taking the time to check into it :) have a great day!